# Movement of items inside enumerate

Tags: enumerate, page-numbering

Question -1

Here i want to move both questions (which are labeled by (i) and (ii)) exactly below the word prove. How can i do this?

Question -2

And give the page number like Page 3 of 5.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7pt}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage[left=1.300cm, right=1.300cm, top=1.300cm, bottom=1.300cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Question~1}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(A),left=0pt]
    \item Prove following results.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
        \item First sub question 
        \item Second sub question  
    \end{enumerate}
    \item  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, with labels of the second level list left and right aligned. One uses the `wide` key and plays with the value of `labelsep`, the other with `widest=`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7pt}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\usepackage[margin=1.300cm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \textbf{Question~1}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(A), left=0pt]
    \item Prove following results.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), wide = 0pt, labelsep=-3pt, leftmargin=*]
        \item First sub question. 
        \item Second sub question. Still some more text. Still some more text. Still some more text. Still some more text. Still some more text.
        \item Third sub question. 
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Prove these other results:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), leftmargin=*, widest=iii]
        \item First other sub question, with a much longer text. Still some more text. Still some more text. Still some more text.
        \item Second other sub question. 
        \item Third other sub question. 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good work but i want label (i) and (ii) in bold. And one request do something for second question.

Comment: When i compile your codes i am finding much space between label and text of question.

Comment: This is because it sets the spacing on the basis of widest label  =(viii). You may change that with `widest=...`

Comment: If you modify your above answer it will a great help to me.

Comment: I've posted two solutions, with different alignments of the roman labels. Of course, some parameters may have to be adjusted, depending on your real list.